# Copy data from one table to another with different column names and column ordering in timescaledb

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I have 2 timescaledb tables with different order of columns and even different column names for for some. Is it possible for me to copy data from one table to another table ?

Essentially the new table has hyper table on it, but the old one does not have hyper table on it.

I have looked at https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/migrate-data/same-db/
However it only seems to tell i need to have same column names and even the same column order in the create table syntax. Can you assist, am new to timescaledb

eg:

```
**table1**
id 
price
datetime_string


**table2**
id 
time
price
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe i have tried that command, it runs for sometime and ends without any error. but the copy of the data has not happened from what i can confirm on the row count.

Comment: Then perhaps you didn't commit the transaction.

Answer (score 2):

I created a minimal example here:

```sql
CREATE TABLE old_table ( id bigserial, time_string text NOT NULL, price decimal);
CREATE TABLE new_table ( time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,  price decimal);
SELECT create_hypertable('new_table', 'time');


INSERT INTO old_table (time_string, price) VALUES
('2021-08-26 10:09:00.01', 10.1),
('2021-08-26 10:09:00.08',  10.0),
('2021-08-26 10:09:00.23',  10.2),
('2021-08-26 10:09:00.40',  10.3);
INSERT INTO new_table SELECT time_string::timestamp as time, price from old_table;
```

Results:

```sql
playground=# \i move_data.sql
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
┌─────────────────────────┐
│    create_hypertable    │
├─────────────────────────┤
│ (19,public,new_table,t) │
└─────────────────────────┘
(1 row)

INSERT 0 4
INSERT 0 4
playground=# table new_table;
┌────────────────────────┬───────┐
│          time          │ price │
├────────────────────────┼───────┤
│ 2021-08-26 10:09:00.01 │  10.1 │
│ 2021-08-26 10:09:00.08 │  10.0 │
│ 2021-08-26 10:09:00.23 │  10.2 │
│ 2021-08-26 10:09:00.4  │  10.3 │
└────────────────────────┴───────┘
(4 rows)
```

Can you try to execute your select first and see if the relation matches the table structure?